# MOCK test Class for POST web service test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, integration, webservicemock

Hi  I am new to integration i need to write the Mock Test class for my webservice test class, i am stuck , please help me to create the mock call out in the APEX

Below my class:

```
public class SFG_WMGAnnuityNotificationWebService implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{

Case objCase = new Case();

public SFG_WMGAnnuityNotificationWebService(Case pCase){
    objCase = pCase;
}

public void execute(QueueableContext context){

    Map<String,List<String>> mapForJson = new Map<String,List<String>>();

    ANN__c annSettings = ANN__c.getInstance();

    if(objCase.Id == null){
        return;
    }
    System.debug('caseList=='+objCase);

    if(objCase.Associated_Documents__r.size() > 0){
        for(Case_Associated_Document__c caseAssoDoc1 :objCase.Associated_Documents__r){
            if(mapForJson.containsKey(caseAssoDoc1.Service_Request__r.Id))
                mapForJson.get(caseAssoDoc1.Service_Request__r.Id).add(caseAssoDoc1.Document_Id__c);
            else
                mapForJson.put(caseAssoDoc1.Service_Request__r.Id,new List<String>{caseAssoDoc1.Document_Id__c});
        }

        //Formation of the JSON Body
        CaseDetails cd = new CaseDetails(objCase.Id,mapForJson.get(objCase.Id));
        String jsonBody = json.serialize(cd);

        //Calling the WebService For POST method
        String endpoint = annSettings.Securian_Services_URL__c +'wmg/imaging/v1/documents/followup/annuity';
        String method = 'POST';

        HTTPRequest req = MM.getHttpRequest(endpoint, method);
        req.setBody(jsonBody);
        // make the request and handle the response
        final Http h = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = h.send(req);
        final Integer status = response.getStatusCode();
        String responseBody = response.getBody();

    }
}


public class CaseDetails {
    public String caseId;
    public List<String> securianDocNumbers;

    CaseDetails(String caseId, List<String> securianDocNumbers){
        this.caseId = caseId;
        this.securianDocNumbers = securianDocNumbers;
    }
}
```

}

TestClass

```
@isTest
```

public class SFG_WMGAnnuityNotificationWebServiceTest {

```
@testSetup static void setup(){

    //create cases
    List<Case> listCases = new List<Case>();
    List<Case_Associated_Document__c> docList = new List<Case_Associated_Document__c>();

    Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('WMG_Operations_Workflow').getRecordTypeId();
    QueueSobject wmgOpsFollowUpQ = [SELECT Id,QueueId,SobjectType FROM QueueSobject where Queue.Name = 'WMG Ops - Follow Up'];

    Case newCase = new Case();
    newCase.recordTypeId = recordTypeId;
    newCase.Type='New Application';
    newCase.Sub_Type__c='ML VA';
    newCase.OwnerId = wmgOpsFollowUpQ.Id;
    newCase.Has_Hit_Follow_Up__c = false;

    listCases.add(newCase);
    insert listCases;

    Case_Associated_Document__c cS = new Case_Associated_Document__c();
    cS.Service_Request__c = newCase.Id;
    cS.Document_Id__c = '3790771';
    docList.add(cS);

    Case_Associated_Document__c cS1= new Case_Associated_Document__c();
    cS1.Service_Request__c = newCase.Id;
    cS1.Document_Id__c = '3790773';
    docList.add(cS1);

    Case_Associated_Document__c cS2 = new Case_Associated_Document__c();
    cS2.Service_Request__c = newCase.Id;
    cS2.Document_Id__c = '3790775';
    docList.add(cS2); 


    insert docList;

}
```

}

i have prepared the data just need to make the Mock Callout please help me out for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create the Mockresponse class and then you need to create the fake response.
in Test class you should call this mockresponse class and not the actual endpoint.
PFB the sample code.

```
    @isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
        // and method.
        System.assertEquals('http://example.com/example/test', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"example":"test"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
```

}

Test class

```
@isTest
private class CalloutClassTest {
     @isTest static void testCallout() {
        // Set mock callout class
```

> Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());

This will call the fake response,not the actual endpoint.

```
        // Call method to test.
        // This causes a fake response to be sent
        // from the class that implements HttpCalloutMock. 
        HttpResponse res = CalloutClass.getInfoFromExternalService();

        // Verify response received contains fake values
        String contentType = res.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
        String actualValue = res.getBody();
        String expectedValue = '{"example":"test"}';
        System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
        System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: can i do it in the same class??

Comment: Yes, you can create inner class and call that class.